# perldoc broken - eclipse / perl 5.16 / mac osx

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl.

From eclipse, I would like auto-complete to work and to show documentation when doing control space bar. I thought I had this feature, or maybe I'm mistaken.

I messed up my Perl installation. And installed Perl 5.16. But perldoc doesn't work in the new installation. I don't know how to use perldoc in my terminal anymore.

:::::::::::::::

UPDATE::

I can execute Perl scripts from the command line. 
I am using Epic installation, and now using 5.16 Perl. Not sure I can rollback or how. So I'm gonna stick with this for now.
What other light weight IDE can I use?

If i do which perldoc
- I get /usr/bin/perldoc

If i do perldoc perldoc
- I get perl version 5.16.0 can't run /usr/bin/perldoc.  Try the alternative(s):
/usr/bin/perldoc5.10.0 (uses Perl 5.10.0)

Does that mean there is another type of perldoc available for 5.16 ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the directory that contains the perldoc executable set in your environment's path?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm new to perl

Hello @airnet and welcome to this wonderful language :) You can find information about Perl and how to learn it at http://www.perl.org/

Btw: the language is called "Perl" and the interpreter "perl".

> I would like auto-complete to work and to show documentation when doing control space bar.

I personally do not use Eclipse for Perl programming and prefer a more lightweight editor. What *plugin* are you using? EPIC? Depending on the kind of Perl code you write, using a fully fledged IDE is probably not sensible.

> I messed up my perl installation.

AFAIK OSX comes with perl pre-installed. Although you probably have to download the documentation seperately. You can access the core documentation online at http://perldoc.perl.org/ and the module documentation at http://www.cpan.org/.

> And installed perl 5.16.

While a new version of perl is a good thing, simply installing a new perl might be suboptimal, considering that some system utilities might rely on a specific version. You can install multiple perl versions with `perlbrew` (available from CPAN) but I don't recommend that until you feel you need a specific feature or the system perl is less than v5.10

> I don't know how to use perldoc in my terminal anymore

You type `perldoc perldoc` ;-) What does the command `which perldoc` return? Is the program missing or is your perl not working anymore? Does this command greet you?

```
$ perl -e 'print "Hello :-)\n"'
```

If not, your perl executable and therefore `perldoc` is not available. Can you somehow roll back your installation and re-instate the default perl?